# How many years does canned jelly stay safe to eat?

Tags: food-safety, jelly

I have several jars of canned grape jelly that are at least 10 years old. Are they still safe to eat?

Answer (score 4):

Canned food basically never expires. That being said, check to make sure there isn't any rust, dents, or swelling on the can, and make sure the food smells okay and there are no cloudy, mushy, or moldy bits of food. It should be safe if it passes all these checks.